# Google Sign In Android requestTokenId

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to sign in with Google. when I am not using the requestTokenId it's working fine, but when I am using, I'm not able to login.

LOGCAT:

```
D/GoogleLoginCallBackHand: handleSignInResult:false

D/GoogleLoginCallBackHand: handleSignInResult:12500:null
```

getting the same issue on emulator and every version of device.

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

```
// Communicator object to communicate with word outside this Fragment
// Fragments relies on host activity to communicate to outside world
// Hence the host activity should set it
Communicator communicator;

// Google Sign
public SignInButton googleLoginButton;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private GoogleLoginCallBackHandler googleLoginCallBackHandler;

//Boolean Variable to track if user is trying to loginWith Google
private boolean mResolvingError = false;

public LoginFragment(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setUpGoogleLogin();
}

private void setUpGoogleLogin() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken("876227381632-k7dittplmjrhechqr0fr7dk3ro8frrte.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .build();
    googleLoginCallBackHandler = new GoogleLoginCallBackHandler(this);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), googleLoginCallBackHandler)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    super.onStart();
    if (!mResolvingError) {  // more about this later
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Google Login Call back set up
    googleLoginButton = (SignInButton)view.findViewById(ViewIds.GOOGLE_SIGNIN_BUTTON.getId());
    googleLoginButton.setOnClickListener(googleLoginCallBackHandler);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == googleLoginCallBackHandler.getRcSignIn()) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        googleLoginCallBackHandler.handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onStop();
}

public GoogleApiClient getmGoogleApiClient() {
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}

public boolean ismResolvingError() {
    return mResolvingError;
}

public void setmResolvingError(boolean mResolvingError) {
    this.mResolvingError = mResolvingError;
}


/**
 * Interface object to communicate with parent activity
 * Fragments relies on host activity to communicate to outside world
 * Hence the host activity should implement this interface
 */

public interface Communicator{
    void communicate();
}

public void setCommunicator(Communicator communicator){
    this.communicator = communicator;
}
```

}

Comment: I am also having the same error. I had this error may be for 2 times  but dont have this problem in my phone. but when I check it in some other phones the problem persist.

Comment: can you post your code please.

Comment: are you still having the problem ?

Comment: yes. is your issue resolved??

Answer (score 2):

I think it's probably due to wrong dev console registration. Make sure in the **same** dev console project, you have both:

1. Your Android client: uniquely identified by package name + signing cert SHA1 (if you have multiple signing cert, e.g. debug key store, test environment cert, production environment cert, you have to register all of them)
2. Your Web typed client
   To check your OAuth2 clients, go to [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential) and select your project.

Make sure to pass the OAuth2 client id of #2 in your Android client.